# Ubuntu partition deleted!

Tags: boot

I have deleted ubuntu being in Windows unintentionally.(Ubuntu 14.04 and Win 7). It shows grub rescue and then I have followed the steps listed from one of the community forum and ended in "BOOTMGR is missing press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart".

Any help to recover my PC.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get back your Ubuntu system, just get a live media of Ubuntu, boot from it and install as usual.
You could perhaps use some recovery software to recover your data but that's the best you can do.

As for getting back your `grub` to work, its pretty much the same, use another system, get an Ubuntu installation media and this time, install `boot-repair` (google it for the ppa and instructions) and use it to reinstall grub. That should get you back to the windows system.

If you want back Ubuntu, get the installation media and install it as usual. If the partition is not deleted, however, you could try to untick the "format this partition" option when installing but I can't guarantee full recovery of data